# Tools to measure cache miss/hit by NUMA node in Linux?

Tags: linux, multithreading, caching, performancecounter, numa

I'm executing a multithreaded program on a AMD abu-dhabi architecture, that has 8 NUMA domains. I'm using numactl to allocate the threads in differents cores, and trying different memory policies. I want to measure the cache miss/hit arranged by NUMA domain but with tools like perf I obtained the an overall counter. I already reviewed tools like numastat, likwid, and hpctoolkit. Do you know of any tool that allows to obtain the standard performance counters separated by NUMA domains?

Comment: Using --per-socket parameter in perf stat allowed me to get counters needed. Although is not exactly what I wanted because in AMD architectures there are 2 NUMA nodes per socket.

Answer (score 1):

Is numastat not sufficient for your need?

```
>numastat
                           node0           node1           node2           node3
numa_hit              2511148413      2668024472      2541805396      2631938751
numa_miss                 687767          186973          510852           79546
numa_foreign              544853         1772504         1306738         1461626
interleave_hit             14268           14291           14281           14309
local_node            2509822983      2667700745      2541325673      2631417570
other_node               2013197          510700          990575          600727

                           node4           node5           node6           node7
numa_hit              2551615375      2287945142      2199394273      2506262343
numa_miss                1178554         1863536         2037710         1278384
numa_foreign             1709984          541463          241266          244888
interleave_hit             14287           14274           14291           14294
local_node            2551212630      2278515165      2198877939      2505436756
other_node               1581299        11293513         2554044         2103971
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. Numastat does not provide enough information because only reveals if a requested page was or not in a particular node, without taking in consideration which node requested the page. I want to know how many requests made a particular node outside its domains and to which node. Do you understand what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

The [Intel PCM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-performance-counter-monitor) package comes with a tool called pcm-numa.x. It tells you how many times each core accessed data from a local NUMA node, and also how many times from a remote node.